# How does windows generate thumbnail previews for proprietary formats?

Tags: command-line, adobe-photoshop, thumbnail-generator

So, I'm wondering how does windows generate a thumbnail for proprietary formats like .psd photoshop files or .clip Clip Studio files.

Im wondering if there is a command line order I can use to get a file for those thumbnails without having to export each file individually.

Answer (score 2):

No, command line is not going to do it.

The file formats you mention are provided by a third party COM plugin (adobe? .. ??) that renders the image when windows asks it to.  Windows takes the resulting bitmap and stores it in the icon cache (proprietary format).

If you care about the specifics, this is done by extending the windows shell through a COM object using c or c++.  This specifically is called a "Thumbnail Image Handler" or "Icon Handler" and implements an interface called `IThumbnailProvider`.  You can follow the chain of what is doing this by looking up the file type in HKCR and identifying the CLSID (class ID) associated it.

That will point you toward the DLL doing the work.  This DLL provides COM interface type `IThumbnailProvider` along with whatever else they wanted to extend the explorer shell with.

[This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers?redirectedfrom=MSDN) has more information if you would like to see the actual API and or verify that I am telling the truth. ;)

Comment: So.. as a CRAZY side note.. if you are a programmer.. there is nothing preventing you from calling the COM object that the explorer calls and getting the resulting bitmap yourself.  :^P  You would need to provide the proper information to the function (of course) but there is no reason that it wouldn't work.